# make variable ?= is really intended for immediate

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How do we assign using `?=` but it's really intended for immediate,
as the 'make' reference manual say that its RHS must be meant to be deferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of the following should work:

```
VAR := $(or $(VAR),newval)
```

or

```
VAR?=val
VAR:=$(VAR)
```

Both have repetition of the variable name, which can't be avoided.

One small difference with the first one -- If $(VAR) is set, but set to blank, then the first option will override it to `newval`, but the `?=` operator will leave it as blank.

As a side note, I'm a bit surprised make hasn't introduced an `?:=` operator yet...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
ifeq ($(origin FOO), undefined)
  FOO := bar
endif
```

However, this means that the variable will be simple if it's set here, and will be whatever type it was before if it was already set.

Or you can use this which has slightly different behavior:

```
FOO ?= bar
FOO := $(FOO)
```

Here `FOO` will always be simple, *but* it will also expand the value of `FOO` if it was set before, which you may not want.

These are your only options.